# Sending and receiving own message

Tags: google-play-games, multiplayer

**Hi everyone.**

I have right now a simple multiplayer game but it is out of sync. 
If I could receive my own message from the RealTimeMessageReceivedListener that would be awesome but I can't.

**How I am sending my info:**

```
    for(Participant p : participants){
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendUnreliableMessage(_gameHelper.getApiClient(),message.getBytes(),roomId,p.getParticipantId());
    }
```

As you can see I'm sending my messages to everyone (even to myself). However at the RealTimeMessageReceivedListener I don't receive any information about my own message.

can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not allow this according to:

- the [Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data) documentation. See section on *Sending  Messages*. Also, the "sender participant" needs to be excluded if you intend to switch to sending broadcast messages with the API instead;
- rationale provided in [issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/284) submitted to the Google Play Plugin for Unity project on GitHub.

Comment: Great answer !! thanks. I saw the second link you gave me and it inspired me of another solution. Send the movement and then wait to receive the ACK from the oponent and execute the movement. The oponent will need to wait some time to execute the movement.....

Comment: Thanks @DomingoGarcia, only started answering questions on SO recently! Interesting alternative you suggest btw.

Comment: @DomingoGarcia, also, if my answer helps, it would be highly appreciated if you can accept it. Shameless plug. :)